# How to connect Context Provider with the Navigators

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I just wonder if there is a similar way to connect our provider with the navigators, switchNavigator in my case, with the way we do with Redux-connect. I have my global context provider in which I store the my states, and want to use the context variables in my createXNavigator objects. 
Thanks.

Comment: This isn't for react-native-navigation, it's react-navigation. Completely different libraries with confusingly similar names...

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it using navigatorRef method. You can see the documentation here;
[Navigating without the navigation prop](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html#docsNav)